# How to apply background-color property in NgClass in nativescript?

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-angular

If i give class with background color property but when i selected that layout color not change.

```
enter code here
<StackLayout verticalAlignment="middle"   [ngClass]="{'iconLayout':  item.selected}" class="backWhiteSelect"   (tap)="drinkSelected(i)"></stackLayout>

CSS:
    .iconLayout{
        margin: 5;  
        height: 90;
        width: 185;
        text-align: center;
        border-radius: 7;
        background-color: rgba(112, 112, 112, 0.15);
    }
```

Comment: The code is incomplete, try sharing Playground sample where the issue can be reproduced.

Comment: Here is the sample of code,https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=8972fs   . If i select the name background color will not changed..

Comment: Are you sure you shared the right version? I don't see any event listeners nor iconLayout being applied to any list item in your code.

Comment: But i see that list, I give iconLayout in CSS file and want to change that CSS after click that item but other than background color all property are applied..

Comment: When are you turning the selected flag on, in the playground it's always false.

Comment: Are you understand my exact  problem?? actually background-color are not change after select item that's the problem..in any condition of ngclass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add new StackLayout with ngClass

```
<ng-template let-item="item" let-i="index">
        <StackLayout verticalAlignment="middle">
            <StackLayout [ngClass]="item?.selected ? 'backWhiteSelect' : 'iconLayout'" (tap)="onTap(item)">
                <Label [text]="item?.name" class="text-center gray-66 h3"></Label>
            </StackLayout>
        </StackLayout>
    </ng-template>
```

tap event in componenet

```
onTap(item) {
    this.interestsItems.forEach(m => m.selected = false);
    item.selected = true;
}
```

Comment: thanks, it was work when 1 option select but when u select multiple option that time they was not applied..

Comment: you can remove "this.interestsItems.forEach(m => m.selected = false);" for multiple selection.